# Can you suggest really good documentation to add google+ OAuth2 to an openapi v3 document running in swagger-ui?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

Basic authentication is working fine in my openapi v3 document running in swagger-ui. Now I want to add Google+ oauth2 authentication.  Can you point me to good newbie documentation how to do this?

I find the configuration options a bit overwhelming as I don't know what options to choose.  Most examples I find using a google search seem to be swagger v2 based or result in me thinking I'm an idiot (which may be the case, but I think it has more to do with knowing little about google oauth flows).

Comment: I believe Google APIs use OpenID Connect (which is based on OAuth 2) and Swagger UI [does not currently support OpenID Connect](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3641).

Comment: I have rotator cuff surgery tomorrow, so won't be looking into this until next week sometime.  I hope what you are saying isn't true.  Yet it isn't a showstopper because basic auth is working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenAPI Specification supports the description of OpenID Connect authorization, however Swagger-UI and Editor have not yet implemented it.

The lack of this functionality has been added to the GitHub swagger/swagger-ui [issues #3641](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3641) list of features not yet supported by Swagger-UI.